# pywinauto type_keys() won't send all keys

Tags: pywinauto

I'm doing some windows automation and I need to import a file into a tool using the 'Open' dialog.  I have this code

```
 w_open_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(title=u'Open', class_name='#32770')[0]
 w_open = app.window_(handle=w_open_handle)

 # Enter filename in edit box
 w_open['File &name'].type_keys("export.txt")
```

When I run this I notice that only the keys **"rt.txt"** get sent to the *File Name* edit box on the window. I've tried other names instead of "export.txt" but in every case the first few keys are not sent. I thought perhaps a small delay between opening the dialog and sending the keys would help, but to no avail.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here?

*Python 3.4.5 (I need this version because of other package dependencies)*

*Windows 10*

Comment: Maybe `.set_focus()` inside `.type_keys()` makes this effect. I'd suggest to try `.set_text("export.txt")` instead.

Comment: Thanks Vasily. It turns out I had the wrong control identifier (the one for the static text next to the actual control). I figured out the correct one and with it set_text() works perfectly.

Comment: Great. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible effects of `type_keys()`:

- It calls `.set_focus()` inside.
- Incorrect control can be found (it's easy to check with `.draw_outline()` method).

More reliable method that sets the whole text is `.set_text("...")` which is available to specific control types only.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
from pywinauto import keyboard
keyboard.send_keys("export.txt")
```

Comment: Please [explain your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers)

Comment: who  need to explain  me ?

Comment: Please edit your question when including large pieces of code, else it quickly become unreadable

Comment: that not my question I just answered the guy who   asked the question and  I answered your comment

Comment: I asked you to edit your answer so as to include your explanations ("try this to ..."). That's how things function in Stack Overflow, I'm just trying my best to make you do the right thing